# What is the difference between vec![] and vec!()

Tags: rust

I found out that I can use both `vec![]` and `vec!()` in my code and they both do the same -- initialize a `Vec`. I found no documentation on the later form though. Is it indeed the same thing? Which one should I use? Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macros [can be invoked using `[]`, `()`, or `{}`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros.html).

Which delimiter is used makes no actual difference to the way it executes, though usually people will use braces for “block-like” or “definition” macros (e.g. tokio’s `select`), brackets for literal-like (`vec`) and parens for function-like expressions (e.g. `println` or `matches`).

Answer (score 0):

In fact there are 3 forms `()`, `[]` and `{}` and they're all identical.

https://users.rust-lang.org/t/braces-square-brackets-and-parentheses-in-macro-call/9984/2

> Yes, they are identical. Use whichever you like best. Usually () is for function-like macros, [] is used for vec![…], and {} is for other cases.